# DiscordAPIError[10062]: Unknown interaction, When I want to get user points from database

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, discord, discord.js

```
     content: "You are already verified!",
            ephemeral: true,
          });
        }
      } else if (interaction.customId === "giverole") {

        const userPoints = await findUser(interaction.member.id);

        await interaction.reply({
          content: "Give role!",
          ephemeral: true,
        });
      };
```

But I get **DiscordAPIError[10062]: Unknown interaction** error. I want to get user points.

I want to get user point and print to consol.

Comment: Have you tried deferring the interaction (`interaction.deferReply()`) before pulling in data from the database and then replying with `interaction.editReply(/* ... */)`? One of the reasons this error may be thrown is when more than 3 seconds elapse between the receiving of the interaction and its reply.

Comment: No worries, I've added the comment as an actual answer so users with a similar issue can easily find the solution, if you could mark it as the accepted answer I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `interaction` must be either deferred or replied to within 3 seconds or the API will return this error. Use `interaction.deferReply()` if you know that your application's logic will take more than 3 seconds, and then reply to it using `interaction.editReply(/* ... */)`.